Claude Artifacts: Blocked form submission to '' because the form's frame is sandboxed and the 'allow-forms' permission is not set
I'm working with the new Claude Artifacts feature and building a bunch of mini tools. Most of them work as expected but for any that include a form tag, I hit this error:

Blocked form submission to '' because the form's frame is sandboxed and the 'allow-forms' permission is not set.

I understand that these artifacts run in a sandboxed environment (the error message makes that clear), but is there any way to make forms usable/shareable? Do I need to copy the code to my own website for it to work?
See this artifact.
